# Does convergence in distribution imply anything about the KL divergence?

Tags: statistics, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Given that some sequence of random variables $X_n$ converge in distribution to $X$ and assuming that the distribution of all $X_n$ are absolutely continuous with respect to a Lebesgue measure, is there anything that we can say about $KL(p(X_n)|p(X))$?